# How to apply a label color to a Pie Chart slice from Google Charts API

Tags: google-visualization

Hej guys , I tried 2 or 3 different functions but i can´t get any of them to work. I want that the label´s from the 3 different stats are colored in for example white. A picture is below.

```
        var options = {'title':'Lead statistik von<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?>',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300,
                   backgroundColor:'#0a0a0a',
                   fontSize:'14',
                   titleTextStyle: {color:'#FFFFFF'}, 
                   slices:
                   {
                   0: { color: 'red' },
                   1: { color: 'purple'},
                   2: { color: 'blue'}
                   },
                   pieSliceTextSlice:{color:'#FFFFFF'}
                  };
```

someone got a hint which funtion to use?

Picture :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to specify legend text color use `legend.textStyle.color` property, for example:

```
var options = {
    legend: {
        textStyle: { color: 'white' }
    }
};
```

According to [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options):

> ```
> legend.textStyle
> ```
>
> An object that specifies the legend text style. The object has this
>   format:
>
> ```
> { color: <string>,
>   fontName: <string>,
>   fontSize: <number>,
>   bold: <boolean>,
>   italic: <boolean> }
>  The color can be any HTML color string, for example: 'red' or '#00cc00'. Also see fontName and fontSize.
>
> Type: object
> Default: {color: 'black', fontName: <global-font-name>, fontSize: <global-font-size>}
> ```

**Example**

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work', 11],
        ['Eat', 2],
        ['Commute', 2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep', 7]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        backgroundColor: '#0a0a0a',
        fontSize: '14',
        legend: {
             textStyle: { color: 'white' }
        }
};

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```